# How to insert data from database with Web Service in java using JAX - RS

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I am new to web services. Please give suggestions how to insert and retrieve data from database using jersey JAX - RS in java?

Comment: So you want to use Jersey to get some data from DB?

Comment: yes i should get it and also insert into DB using it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is an example of a **JAX-RS** service implemented as a session bean using **JPA** for persistence and **JAXB** for messaging might look like.

**CustomerService**

```
package org.example;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CustomerService",
                        type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void create(Customer customer) {
        entityManager.persist(customer);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("{id}")
    public Customer read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Customer.class, id);
    }

    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public void update(Customer customer) {
        entityManager.merge(customer);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        Customer customer = read(id);
        if(null != customer) {
            entityManager.remove(customer);
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("findCustomersByCity/{city}")
    public List<Customer> findCustomersByCity(@PathParam("city") String city) {
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findCustomersByCity");
        query.setParameter("city", city);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

**Customer**

Below is an example of one of the entities.  It contains both JPA and JAXB annotations.

```
package org.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "findCustomersByCity",
            query = "SELECT c " +
                    "FROM Customer c " +
                    "WHERE c.address.city = :city")
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;

}
```

**For More Information**

- [Part 1 - Data Model](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - JPA](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - JAXB (using MOXy)](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - RESTful Service (using an EJB session bean)](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The client](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)

---

**UPDATE**

> what are the jars required

You can deploy a JAX-RS/EJB/JPA/JAXB application to any Java EE 6 compliant application server without requiring any additional server set up.  Programming the client you can get the JAX-RS APIs from the Jersey (http://jersey.java.net/), and the JPA and JAXB APIs from EclipseLink (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/).

> and where the database connections is written

**JDBC Resource & Connection Pool**

You need to configure a connection pool on your application server. Below are the steps to do this on GlassFish.  The steps will vary depending on the application server you are using.

1. Copy the JDBC driver (ojdbc14.jar) to /glashfish/lib
2. Launch the Administration Console
3. Create a Connection Pool:

   1. Name = CustomerService
   2. Resource Type = 'javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource'
   3. Database Vendor = Oracle (or whatever database vendor is appropriate to your database)
   4. Click Next and fill in the following "Additional Properties":
   5. User (e.g. CustomerService)
   6. Password (e.g. password)
   7. URL (e.g. jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE)
   8. Use the "Ping" button to test your database connection
4. Create a JDBC Resource called "CustomerService"

   1. JNDI Name = CustomerService
   2. Pool Name = CustomerService (name of the connection pool you created in the previous step)

**JPA Configuration**

Then we reference the database connection we created above in the `persistence.xml` file for our JPA entities as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="CustomerService" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>CustomerService</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.example.Customer</class>
        <class>org.example.Address</class>
        <class>org.example.PhoneNumber</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.ejb_or_metadata" value="WARNING" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.timestamp" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.thread" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.session" value="false"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.exceptions" value="false"/> 
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="SunAS9"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: what are the jars required and where the database connections is written

Comment: @Praveensai - I have updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: I am using tomcat server and mysql database, how to implement in coding for database connections

Comment: For these two annotations @Stateless,@LocalBean.what are the jars required

Comment: @Praveensai - Those annotations are for EJB session beans.  I do not believe that Tomcat supports EJB.  The following article may help create a Tomcat friendly service:  http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html. Without EJB you will need to create the JPA EntityManager yourself and do your own transaction management.

Comment: @Blaise Doughan Great answer +1

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this [link](http://javing.blogspot.in/2012/04/using-fun-chalk-board-to-explain-how.html), there is a video tutorial that explains one way how it can be done.

So the video is explaining how a web service retrieves some value to tell the client that the given credentials match against some data in a database.

**This is how the method that handle the client request looks like:**

```
@POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/login")
    public Response login(@FormParam("email") String email, @FormParam("password") String password) {

        Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = null;
        
        boolean result = entityFacade.doLogin(email, password);
        if (result) {
             responseBuilder = Response.ok("Success");//Login good!
        }
        else {            
            responseBuilder = Response.ok("Wrong credentials!");//Login bad!
        }

        return responseBuilder.build();
    }
```

**This Web service transfers the credentials to the business layer where an EJB will perform a select operation in the database:**

```
@Stateless
public class EntityFacade implements EntityFacadeLocal {

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction ut;
    private CredentialJpaController controller;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {        
        controller = new CredentialJpaController(ut, Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ROLEProject-ejbPU"));
    }


    public boolean doLogin(String email, String password){        
        return controller.loginWithParameters(email,password);
    }
}
```

**The EJB relies in a service class that will do the task of interact with the database**

```
public class CredentialJpaController implements Serializable {

    public CredentialJpaController(UserTransaction utx, EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        this.utx = utx;
        this.emf = emf;
    }
    private UserTransaction utx = null;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
    public boolean loginWithParameters(String email, String password) {
        boolean result = false;
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        Long l = (Long) em.createNamedQuery("loginquery").setParameter("emailParam", email).setParameter("passwordParam", password).getSingleResult();
        if (l == 1) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Finally to be able to interact with the DB, the data must be represented as a JPA entity. 
Also to be able to marshal the selected row back to the client as whatever MediaType is desired, the entity must contain some JaxB annotations:**

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name = "CREDENTIALS")
@NamedQuery(name="loginquery", query="SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Credential c WHERE c.email = :emailParam AND c.password = :passwordParam")
public class Credential implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @XmlElement
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

     @XmlElement
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here is some sample client code so you can see one of the ways how the web-service can be called:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/ROLEProject-war/role/login" method="POST">
            Email <input name="email"/>
            Password <input type="password" name="password"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps to give you an idea.

To do insert data the process is almost the same, just use the method persist() instead of find() from the entity manager.

Comment: can you send the entire codeof this example

Thanks & Regards

Comment: @Praveensai That is all the relevant stuff. The rest is just additional code not relevant, if i post all the code i will exceed the maximum characters. 
Just do the following:
1-Create the entity and make sure the table is created in the DB
2-Create the CRUD facade
3-Create the webservice as explained above.

All i can still give you in the answer is give you some sample code how the client calls it(Ill paste it in 2 mins). 
Use the debugger from your favourite IDE to follow each step.

Comment: Thank you @sfrj, but what are the jar files to be added and where the database connections,login method should be written

Comment: @Praveensai
All the jar files needed are included in JEE 6 JDK.
If you want them separetly you will need to download I-Stack and also Jersey, but not really sure what else. I think you could comment on Blaise Doughan answer about what are all the tools involved in this process, he is really good at this topic. I asked a similar question a couple of days ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029976/how-a-jee6-enterprise-application-that-offers-rest-web-services-should-be-organi

Comment: @Praveensai Sorry my friend but i prefer not to paste my mail id in here. If you want you can follow my blog. Or invite me to chat room here in stackoverflow, there i could give you the email.

Comment: can i send my mail id then you can send request to it

Comment: how to retrive data from database using my code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091499/how-to-retrive-data-from-database-using-webservices-jax-rs-in-eclipse-using/10094232#comment12931322_10094232

Comment: Can you tell how to login using the webservices in java