# How to insert and retrieve data from database with Web Service in java using JAX - RS and tomcat in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, jersey

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert data from database with Web Service in java using JAX - RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069901/how-to-insert-data-from-database-with-web-service-in-java-using-jax-rs)

How to insert and retrieve data from database using JAX - RS(Jersey) and tomcat in java using eclipse? Please give the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate:: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10069901/818557

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use hibernate or Spring configuration for database.You can easily integrate jersey with spring.Create Common POJO class for both Jersey and database.

Here are some links -

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/