# Spring JPA with Jersey

Tags: spring, jpa, jersey-2.0

I am writing a rest service using Jersey. The data access layer will be developed using Spring JPA. I will be interested to know how can I pass database properties to the Repository layer.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at @Blaise Doughan's answer to a similar question

[How to insert data from database with Web Service in java using JAX - RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069901/how-to-insert-data-from-database-with-web-service-in-java-using-jax-rs)